# Выборный показ Tab'ов

Tags: android, checkbox, tab

Имеется приложение с кучей Tab'ов внутри одного Fragment

```
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;


public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private static ViewPager viewPager;
    private final int int_items = 12;

    public BlankFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) x.findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabs.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });


        int[][] tabStates = new int[][] {
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected},
                new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_selected}
        };

        int[] tabColors = new int[] {
                getResources().getColor((R.color.TabTextColor)),
                getResources().getColor((R.color.TabTextColor)),
                getResources().getColor((R.color.TabTextColor))
        };

        ColorStateList tabList = new ColorStateList(tabStates, tabColors);
        tabs.setTextColor(tabList);

        return x;
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new Tab1(); 
                case 1 : return new Tab2();
                case 2 : return new Tab3();
                case 3 : return new Tab4();
                case 4 : return new Tab5();
                case 5 : return new Tab6();
                case 6 : return new Tab7();
                case 7 : return new Tab8();
                case 8 : return new Tab9();
                case 9 : return new Tab10();
                case 10 : return new Tab11();
                case 11 : return new Tab12();
            }

            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return int_items; }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Заголовок1";
            case 1 :
                return "Заголовок2";
            case 2 :
                return "Заголовок3";
            case 3 :
                return "Заголовок4";
            case 4 :
                return "Заголовок5";
            case 5 :
                return "Заголовок6";
            case 6 :
                return "Заголовок7";
            case 7 :
                return "Заголовок8";
            case 8 :
                return "Заголовок9";
            case 9 :
                return "Заголовок10";
            case 10 :
                return "Заголовок11";
            case 11 :
                return "Заголовок12";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Поставлена задача отображать только те Tab'ы, которые выберет пользователь(в отдельном Activity посредством списка с CheckBox)

Понятно, что переменную int_items(количество отображаемых Tab'ов) можно передать из класса со списком(посредством счетчика), но вот как реализовать выбор конкретных Tab'ов никак не могу придумать

Comment: Адаптер перепишите чтобы данные брал из списка, и формируйте этот список как угодно потом.